# Biblography without a page break using aastex62

Tags: bibliographies, aastex

I am trying to keep my document compact and for some reason it is not letting me put the references on the empty bit of the page no matter what I try. Apart from minipages which work but mess up the style of the references.

My tex file: https://www.overleaf.com/read/rdcwwzwvhgsy

Comment: Hi I work for AAS Journals. It is on purpose for Research Notes (see line 1254 of aastex62.cls). You can undo it by editing your CLS file to remove the \if ... \fi block.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like that but missed that /newpage. 
And I was trying to make an arXiv version as the article is already published and wanted it to be compact.